# C#: Possibly a polymorphism function? But not sure

Tags: c#

I'm currently working on a lab for class and we were told to make a method in the main form called "DisplayInformation. that accepts a parameter of type Time and then displays the Time objects information" Which doesn't sound difficult to me but we're told to use 2 buttons to access this method. One just goes to the base class and gets the current time and returns it. The other is suppose to go to a derived class. And this is where my problem begins.

```
private void btnDisplayTime_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DisplayInformation(time1);


}
```

And this is the DisplayInformation function I'm not sure about:

```
private string DisplayInformation (Time zone)
        {
            time1 = zone;
            time1.displayTime();
           // extTime1.displayTime();
            return "okay";

        }//end of DisplayInformation
```

When i call DisplayInformation with the first button it'll go just fine.
And if i make a call from the second button to this method it'll be fine as well. But i need  to be able to pick and choose which class i go to. It's difficult to explain really. 
I just need to be able to call from each button to that method and get a different output depending on the button. I'm not sure if this would just be an if statement or what.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CIS247A_Week_4_Lab_BREWER
{
class Time
{
    private const int MIN_HOUR = 0;
    private const int MAX_HOUR = 24;
    internal int hour;
    internal int minute;

    public Time()
    {
        hour = 12;
        minute = 00;
    }//end of Time

    public Time(int Hour, int Minute)
    {
        hour = Hour;
        minute = Minute;
    }//end of Time

    public int incrementHour(int step)
    {
        if (step > 0 && hour < 24)
        {
            //step = step % hour;
            hour = (hour + step) % 24;

            return hour;
        }//end of if

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a positive number.");

            return 0;
        }//end of else
    }//end of incrementHour

    public int incrementMinute(int step)
    {
        if (step > 0 && minute < 60)
        {
            minute = (minute + step) / 60;

            return 0;
        }//end of if

        else if (step < 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a positive number.");
            minute = 0;
            return 0;
        }//end of else if
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unknown error.");
            return 0;
        }
    }//end of incrementMinute
    public virtual string displayTime()
    {
        DateTime time = DateTime.Now; // Use current time
        string format = "MMM ddd d HH:mm yyyy"; // Use this format
        MessageBox.Show(time.ToString(format)); // Write to console

        return time.ToString(format);
    }//end of displayTime

    public int Hour
    {
        get { return hour; }


        set
        {
            if (value < MIN_HOUR)
            {
                hour = 0;
                MessageBox.Show("Hour value " + value.ToString() + " cannot be negative. Reset to " + MIN_HOUR.ToString(),
                "Invalid Hour", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
            else
            {
                //take the modulus to ensure always less than 24 hours
                //works even if the value is already within range, or value equal to 24
                hour = value % MAX_HOUR;
            }
        }
    }
    public int Minute
    {
        get { return minute; }
        set
        {
            if (value < 0)
            {
                minute = 0;
                //MessageBox.Show("cannot be negitive" , MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
            else
            {
                minute = value % 60;
            }


        }
    }
}//end of Time Class
}//end of Namespace
```

And the extendedtime class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace CIS247A_Week_4_Lab_BREWER
{

class ExtendedTime : Time
{

    private string timeZone{get; set;}

    public ExtendedTime() : base()
    {
        timeZone = "CDT";

    }//end of ExtendedTime

    public ExtendedTime(int Hour, int Minute, String TimeZone) :base(Hour, Minute)
    {

        timeZone = TimeZone;
    }//end of ExtendedTime

    public override string displayTime()
    {
        //return base.displayTime();
        MessageBox.Show(base.displayTime() + timeZone);
        return base.displayTime() + timeZone;
    }//end of DisplayTime

}//end of ExtendedTime class

}//end of namespace
```

And just for time sake the section of the form i'm working on:

```
public partial class frmTime : Form
    {
        Time time1;
        ExtendedTime extTime1;


    public frmTime()
    {
        //DateTime Ctime = DateTime.Now; // Use current time
       // Ctime = new DateTime();
       // label1.Text = Ctime.ToString();
        InitializeComponent();
        time1 = new Time();
        extTime1 = new ExtendedTime();
    }


    private void DisplayInformation (Time zone)
    {
        time1 = zone;
       // time1.displayTime();
        extTime1.displayTime();
        //return "okay";

    }//end of DisplayInformation
    //exit Button (btnExit)
    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();//closes the program

    }

    private void btnDisplayTime_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayInformation(time1);


    }
```

Comment: Can you provide both classes?  We can't discuss polymorphism and inheritance without the classes.

Comment: Are you using the same event handler for both buttons ?

Comment: Yeah. Just being pass with a different variable
"DisplayInformation(extTime1);"

Comment: Can you not just call time1.displayTime() from one button and extTime1.displayTime() from the other or are you not meant to be using two different instances like this? or in fact call zone.displayTime()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your DisplayInformation class if you are passing in a Time object from one click handler and an extTime object from the other handler then you should be able to just call the displayTime method.

```
private void DisplayInformation (Time zone)
{
    zone.displayTime();
}
```

on the Time one it will obviously call the base method. On the extTime one despite the fact you are treating it as a Time object it will call the overridden method.

Comment: /face palm >____> REALLY? /explodes. Thanks Chris.

Comment: dammit. I was trying not to post useful answer so I could get the unsung hero badge. :( Still, I think I'm 11 out of 44 still. ;-)

Comment: @allthosemiles: this was almost certainly the exact lesson you were meant to be learning so just make sure you go and remember it now, ok? :)

Comment: ^.^ Indeed sir. Thank you. Gotcha. I almost feel like this isn't the full lesson however lmao because of all the extra sections of this program. But thanks!

Comment: OK. Well it is certainly a key lesson anyway. Good luck with the rest. :)